# Pass parameters to button action in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

When setting the action with the "addTarget" method on a button in Swift, is there a way for me to pass a parameter to the function I want to trigger?
Say I had a simple scenario like this:

```
let button = UIButton()
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didPressButton), for: .touchUpInside)

@objc func didPressButton() {
    // do something
}
```

Obviously the above code works fine, but say I wanted the 'didPressButton' function to take in a parameter:

```
@objc func didPressButton(myParam: String) {
    // do something with myParam
}
```

Is there a way I can pass a parameter into the function in the 'addTarget' method?
Something like this:

```
let button = UIButton()
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didPressButton(myParam: "Test")), for: .touchUpInside)

@objc func didPressButton(myParam: String) {
    // do something with myParam
}
```

I'm coming from a JavaScript background and in JavaScript it's pretty simple to achieve this behavior by simply passing an anonymous function that would then call the 'didPressButton' function. However, I can't quite figure how to achieve this with swift. Can a similar technique be used by using a closure? Or does the '#selector' keyword prevent me from doing something like that?

Thank you to anyone who can help!

Comment: Yes, you can, see below, you need to use `addAction` inner versions of Swift, you can not use `addTarget`

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no.

The target selector mechanism only sends the target in the parameters. If the string was a part of a subclass of UIbutton then you could grab it from there.

```
class SomeButton: UIButton {
  var someString: String

}

@objc func didPressButton(_ button: SomeButton) {
  // use button.someString
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do that in iOS. You can get the View in the selector in your case it is a button.

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonClick(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

@objc func buttonClick(_ view: UIButton) {
    switch view.titleLabel?.text {
    case "Button":
        break
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Well in my case I needed to pass one UIlabel text as a parameter, so I added a button over it. Set its textlabel as the UIlabel. Catch that in selector by casting the sender into UIButton and then retrieving the textLabel.

```
UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, bottomheight, CGRectGetWidth(bottomview.frame), note.frame.size.height)];

btn.titleLabel.text = note.text;
[btn addTarget:[self.view parentFocusEnvironment] action:@selector(showDispatcherNote:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

--------selector method-----------------

UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;

NSString * text = btn.titleLabel.text;
```